# How do I transform a TF-IDF matrix into an overall dictionary of the top 10 words

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, tf-idf, corpus

I am trying to get the overall tf-idf score of words over a few texts. I am following the manual method of calculating tf-idf seen here: https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-feature-engineering-using-tf-idf-e8b9d00e7e76

I am using these sentences: ['the man went out for a walk','the children sat around the fire']

The results can be seen in this pandas dataframe table:

[image]

The dictionaries that are used to show the tf-idf result can be seen here:

```
[{'a': 0.09902102579427789, 'for': 0.09902102579427789, 'man': 0.09902102579427789, 'out': 0.09902102579427789, 'the': 0.0, 'walk': 0.09902102579427789, 'went': 0.09902102579427789}, 

{'around': 0.11552453009332421, 'children': 0.11552453009332421, 'fire': 0.11552453009332421, 'sat': 0.11552453009332421, 'the': 0.0}]
```

How can I transform this list of TF-IDF result dictionaries into one dictionary of the top tf-idf results overall, in order?

Answer (score 0):

Since we are working with just a few sentences here and given nature of TF-IDF, i.g. word frequency in overall document vs. word frequency in overall corpus, we could just put your result in order from bigger to smaller. To do that we can use a method to sort the dictionary you shown in your question.

```
def sort_dictionary(my_dict):
    return {k: v for k, v in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
```

Doing so we get a result of:

```
{'a': 0.09902102579427789, 'for': 0.09902102579427789, 'man': 0.09902102579427789, 'out': 0.09902102579427789, 'walk': 0.09902102579427789, 'went': 0.09902102579427789, 'the': 0.0}
```

In line with the documents, or sentences, we used as input. Although we have thirteen words in the sentences, we only have 7 unique ones, but had we had hundreds of them, we could limit our search to the first ten in the sorted dictionary and that would give us a top ten.

Comment: This is not what I am trying to achieve. I want to get each words overall weight against all texts, not just one text like you have done here. Your solution sorts one of the texts results. I want a one row TF-IDF weight for each word of all texts overall, which could then be sorted.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your comment. My answer is based on your solution presented in the question you posted. I believe this dictionary represents exactly what you are looking for, since, as you mentioned, "The dictionaries that are used to show the tf-idf result can be seen here". We can confirm that noticing that the weight for 'the' is 0, that is because that word is present in all texts in your corpus, here represented by ['the man went out for a walk','the children sat around the fire'] - a list containing two elements.